# Making a list of unbound variables (LISP)

Tags: list, lisp

I have the following LISP code

```
(defun l (x y) (list x y))
```

when I do `(l a a)` I get an error that A has no value.

I want this to return (a a). How can I overcome this?

Comment: You can't. Lisp does not work that way. Symbols need to be quoted, otherwise they are evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you mean is that you want a list of "symbols". When a symbol is bound to a value, then it becomes a variable.  You can do this by "quoting" the symbols when you pass it to your `l` function:

```
(l 'a 'a)
```

Recommended reading: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html

Comment: The point is that I don't want to pass it in that way. And, yes I meant symbols since they aren't bound to anything. I need to call is like (l a a) for some symbol a

Comment: If you want to provide a syntax without needing to quote symbols, you'll need to write this as a macro.  It might be good to explain what you're trying to do here on a higher level.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

You can write a code-walking macro that replaces references to unbound variables with quotations if you have sufficient macroexpansion-time access to the lexical context to determine which variables are lexically unbound.  By programming by wishful thinking, the macro could look something like the following:

```
(defmacro with-ad-hoc-quotations (&body forms &environment outer-env)
  (walk:map-variable-references
   (lambda (var env)
     (if (walk:lexically-bound-p var env)
         var
         `(if (boundp ',var)  ;deal with dynamic bindings
              (symbol-value ',var)
              ',var)))
   `(progn ,@forms)
   outer-env))
```

where `walk:map-variable-references` is assumed to be a function that takes a form and replaces all variable references within the supplied form with the result of applying the supplied function  to the variable name and the lexical context; and where `walk:lexically-bound-p` is assumed to return a generalized boolean that tells you whether a given symbol is lexically bound in a given context.

You will need to discover implementations of the latter functions yourself (and `walk:lexically-bound-p` might need support from the Lisp implementation), but that's the general idea.  Usage of the macro would be as follows:

```
(with-ad-hoc-quotations (l a a))
;=> (A A)
```

or, a more interesting example,

```
(defvar *c* 20)

(with-ad-hoc-quotations
  (let ((b 10))
    (list a b *c*)))
;=> (A 10 20)
```

### Implementation in SBCL

As a proof of concept, this is an SBCL-specific implementation using `sb-walker`:

```
(defmacro with-ad-hoc-quotations (&body forms &environment outer-env)
  (sb-walker:walk-form
   `(progn ,@forms)
   outer-env
   (lambda (form ctx env)
     (declare (ignore ctx))
     (typecase form
       (symbol
        (if (sb-walker:var-lexical-p form env)
            form
            `(if (boundp ',form)
                 (symbol-value ',form)
                 ',form)))
       (t
        form)))))
```

Or, if you prefer the more general version described above, we can implement the two required functions for SBCL as follows:

```
#+sbcl
(defun lexically-bound-p (var env)
  (sb-walker:var-lexical-p var env))

#+sbcl
(defun map-variable-references (fn form &optional env)
  (sb-walker:walk-form form
                       env
                       (lambda (expr ctx env)
                         (declare (ignore ctx))
                         (typecase expr
                           (symbol (funcall fn expr env))
                           (t      expr)))))
```

### Implementation using `hu.dwim.walker`

Finally, the following is an implementation based on the portable `hu.dwim.walker` library (available via [Quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org/)).  Beware that it *does not* take the enclosing lexical context into account, so you generally need to call it on the top level for it to work correctly.

```
(defmacro with-ad-hoc-quotations (&body forms)
  (hu.dwim.walker:unwalk-form
   (hu.dwim.walker:rewrite-ast
    (hu.dwim.walker:walk-form `(progn ,@forms))
    (lambda (parent type form)
      (declare (ignore parent type))
      (typecase form
        (hu.dwim.walker:free-variable-reference-form
         (hu.dwim.walker:walk-form `',(hu.dwim.walker:name-of form)))
        (t
         form))))))
```